# change imagebutton from spinner

Tags: android

Im using a `spinner` and i was wondering how can you get an `item` from the `spinner` to appear in an `image button` the images are using string as value.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_up);
    spinnerListener();
    St = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Namess);
    imageButton01 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);
 }


    private void spinnerListener() {

         ArrayList<Name> players = List_content.ENTRY_LIST_PLAYERS;
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Line_up.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            {for (Name p : players){adapter.add(p.f_name);}};
            playerss.setAdapter(adapter); 
            playerss.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View v,
                            int position, long itemId) {

            } 

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
    }
            public void goalkeeper(View v){
                st.performClick();

    }
```

Comment: You should make your question far more clear. Give me an example maybe.

You can generally change your ImageButton image using setDrawableResourceId() method.

Comment: well when i click on an imageButton i want the spinner to open and when i select a item from the spinner i want the image button i press to change it image to the image i pick in the spinner

Comment: OK I will tell you what to do.

Comment: Are you still alive?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here's the trick:

When ImageButton is clicked, you just need to call `performClick()` on the spinner object.

```
int[] pictureIds = {
        R.drawable.picture1,
//add as many picture IDs as you want
        R.drawable.picture2
}

imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        spinner.performClick();

    }
});

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
            imageButton.setImageResource(pictureIds[position]);             
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Don't forget to set spinner adapter just as you did correctly in your question.